# Making Bloch's builder pattern thread-safe: Rechecking necessary in enclosing constructor if NEVER invalid?

Tags: java, multithreading, inner-classes, builder-pattern

I have recently learned [Joshua Bloch's builder pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) for creating objects with many optional fields. I've been using something like it for years, but never used an inner-class until Bloch's book suggested it to me. I love it.

I understand that another thread may alter the bulider's configuration, before it's actually built (with `build()`), such that it may be necessary to re-validate all values in the constructor of the enclosing class. Below is an example of a builder class that optionally reverifies its data.

So my question is this: Assuming this is a robust enough design, when there are defaults for all values--knowing this class is a poor choice for using defaults--and when every set-attempt is validated, is this re-check necessary? Although it may be *different*, it would never be *invalid*. Is that correct?

(Although this design is manageable, it is certainly complicated by the potential need for re-verification. And, honestly, I never multi-thread, but I don't want to make my library unusable by people that do.)

Thank you for any advice.

```
/**
   <P><CODE>java ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl</CODE></P>
 **/
public class ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {

      //Don't reverify
      ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl rvbdx = new ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg().
         name("Big Bird").age(6).build();

      System.out.println(rvbdx.sName);
      System.out.println(rvbdx.iAge);

      //Do reverify
      rvbdx = new ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg().
         reverifyInEnclosing().
         name("Big Bird").age(6).build();
   }

   public final String sName;
   public final int    iAge;
   /**
      <P>Create a new <CODE>ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl</CODE> with defaults.</P>
   **/
   public ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl()  {
      //Does not reverify. No need.
      this(new ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg());
   }
   private ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl(ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg rbdx_c)  {
      sName = rbdx_c.sName;
      iAge = rbdx_c.iAge;
      ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg.zcibValues(rbdx_c, sName, iAge, "constructor");
   }
   public static class Cfg  {
      private String  sName   = null;
      private int     iAge    = -1;
      private boolean bReVrfy = false;
      public Cfg()  {
         //Defaults
         bReVrfy = false;
         name("Broom Hilda");
         age(127);
      }
      //Self-returning configuration...START
         //No way to unset.
         public Cfg reverifyInEnclosing()  {
            bReVrfy = true;
            return  this;
         }
         public Cfg name(String s_name)  {
            zcib_name(s_name, "name");
            sName = s_name;
            return  this;
         }
         public Cfg age(int i_age)  {
            zcib_age(i_age, "age");
            iAge = i_age;
            return  this;
         }
      //Self-returning configuration...END
      //Validate config...START
         public static final void zcibValues(ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl.Cfg rbdx_c, String s_name, int i_age, String s_clgFunc)  {
            try  {
               if(!rbdx_c.bReVrfy)  {
                  return;
               }
            }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
               throw  new NullPointerException("zcibValues: rbdx_c");
            }
            zcib_name(s_name, s_clgFunc);
            zcib_age(i_age, s_clgFunc);
         }
         public static final void zcib_name(String s_name, String s_clgFunc)  {
            if(s_name == null  ||  s_name.length() == 0)  {
               throw  new IllegalArgumentException(s_clgFunc + ": s_name (" + s_name + ") is null or empty.");
            }
         }
         public static final void zcib_age(int i_age, String s_clgFunc)  {
            if(i_age < 0)  {
               throw  new IllegalArgumentException(s_clgFunc + ": i_age (" + i_age + ") is negative.");
            }
         }
      //Validate config...END
      public ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl build()  {
         return  (new ReverifyBuilderInEnclosingCnstrXmpl(this));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: A builder is usually not thread-safe, because it's usually used, by a single thread, to construct a thread-safe, immutable object, that is made available to multiple threads after it has been constructed. Making everything thread-safe in case someone needs it is usually a bad idea (the thread-safe Vector and Hashtable classes, BTW, have been replaced by thread-unsafe classes: ArrayList and HashMap). Let the end-user make its code thread-safe if he needs to.

Comment: If that's true, it's a relief. Maintaining the extra "reusuable" crash-if-bad code is a pain. I'd just clearly document that it is not threadsafe.

Comment: @JBNizet - Sorry but I totally disagree with almost everything you said in your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly - the builder pattern is **not** inherently thread unsafe. I am not sure how you are concluding that it is. Each thread that intends to use the builder will create its own `Builder` object, populate it in Joshua Bloch's pragmatic and beautiful way and use it to construct the object. There are no `static` variables being affected anywhere in that mechanism, there is no thread unsafety unless you introduce it yourself.

Your concern about validation is - in my humble opinion - a gross pre-optimisation that produces hideously contrived and horribly bloated code. **There is no reason to try to avoid validation just because you know the data is valid**. Validation is almost always trivial and often takes little more that a few instructions. By bloating the class with these horrible static validation methods you are probably adding thousands of times more cpu cycles just to load this bloated code than you are saving by avoiding the validation.

Compare your contrived and bloated code with this lucid, succinct and patently correct **and thread safe** code and see what I mean:

```
public class Thing {

    public final String name;
    public final int age;

    public Thing() {
        this(new Thing.Builder());
    }

    private Thing(Thing.Builder builder) {
        name = builder.name;
        age = builder.age;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private String name = null;
        private int age = -1;

        public Builder() {
            name("Broom Hilda");
            age(127);
        }

        public Builder name(String name) {
            if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Thing.Builder.name (" + name + ") is null or empty.");
            }
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder age(int age) {
            if (age < 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Thing.Builder.age (" + age + ") is negative.");
            }
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Thing build() {
            return (new Thing(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As recommended by Bloch and implemented by you, the Builder is a static class. How is that not a potential multi-threading issue? Not for invalid data, per se, but for changed data. I'm not trying to avoid validation! The whole point of my question is to  avoid *redundant* validation and to prevent exactly those "contrived and bloated" static functions from ever having to exist. If it were required that the data had to be redundantly validated, both in the builder and in its enclosing constructor, it's the best design I could think of. OldCurmudgeon indeed.

Comment: The keyword `static` on an inner class means something totally different. This is not a `static` class in the sense that all it's variables are essentially global - it is a `static` class in the sense that it does not need an enclosing `Thing` class to exist for it to be created. All it's instance variables are as thread safe as any other.

Comment: Now that is something I didn't know. I did read an article today, which I tried to re-find but can't, about how it is a multi-threading problem as I mentioned, and therefore needed the redundant check in the enclosing constructor. I'll post if I find it. -- I spilled soda on your lawn purposfully, but the good news is that it was black cherry Wishniak.

Comment: The builder you posted is not thread-safe, and what you're saying in your introduction ("Each thread that intends to use the builder will create its own Builder object") is basically exactly what I said in my comment: each thread uses its own non-threadsafe builder to construct a thread-safe immutable Thing.

Comment: @JBNizet - Surely if each thread has it's own builder the only way for it to be not thread-safe would be if there was some sort of shared state. I don't see any shared state.

Comment: That's my point: the builder is not thread-safe, and it's not a problem, because it's usually not shared between threads.

Comment: Minor (maybe) note, but using the public final vars break encapsulation, an OO principle.  Sources: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/176876/why-shouldnt-i-be-using-public-variables-in-my-java-class

Comment: @michaelok - are you suggesting that the **private** instance variables in the `Builder` object should be accessed through getters and setters? You have totally missed the point of the builder pattern. The whole reason of the Builder pattern is that the builder does all the gnarly bits like parameter checking etc. etc. while the object it builds remains slim and lightweight. Why add completely unnecessary functionality to it?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon No, those are already private, I was talking about the public vars in your "Thing" class, not the builder. See the links I included above. I know long back there was a discussion amongst Java thought leaders that C# "properties" (or was it VB?) were good, so maybe I missed the shift somewhere, but the examples I looked at (Bloch) use the standard convention, i.e. private vars. (Perhaps that was for brevity? It is concise.) Also might be helpful with example of invariant check in Build method. http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2

Answer (score 6):

You are misunderstanding the pattern on an architectural level: all data during construction is tied to the local thread and not to be exposed to any external handler. The very moment build is called, the now **finalized** set of parameters is passed to an **immutable** object, which **then** first should verify the validity of those parameters in the constructor, then either return the final object or throw an exception.

As long as you keep the builder parameters thread-local, you cannot cause any threading-issues. If you violate this rule, you should ask yourself if what you are doing is correct and/or how you could solve it in a more fine-grained way.

So if you in your example need to use the builder from different threads, the simplest and safest way is to create a new builder instance instead of doing it statically. If you worry about performance, [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) is your friend.